# Share the width for menu items with equal padding using CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a dynamic menu with a few items. I wanted the items to share the space available such that the bigger text takes more space. And all of them will have equal padding so that the hover color will fill the space defined for it.

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
|   Test   |   Test Very Bigger Item   |  Test Bigger item  |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

The menu will look similar to above without the border. On hover, the background color will need to fill up the space around it.

```css
ul {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Very Very Large Bigger Item
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Bigger item
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code ensures correct spacing but the hover does not take up the space available.

Comment: Does it need to be 600px wide?

Comment: @FloRagossnig the ul will have a width, even though not necessary to be 600px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this style (everything is dynamic here) -

CSS (modified) -

```
ul {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
li {
  flex: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
li:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML (no change) -

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Very Very Large Bigger Item
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Bigger item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zsdwgs?file=styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

I do some changes:

```css
ul {
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px dashed blue;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Very Very Large Bigger Item
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Bigger item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok, but I want the extra spaces to be divided to each of the item. So that hover will be covered on it.

Comment: I edit the snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, according to your comment the **width** of the `ul` must not necessarily be 600px. I'd suggest setting a `max-width: 600px` and just give  the `li` elements an extra padding.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  padding: 0 2em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-width: max-content;
}
li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Very Very Large Bigger Item
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Bigger item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Depending on the location of the `ul` you can set the elements inside the flex container either to `justify-content: flex-start` (if the `ul` is placed on the left side of the screen) or `justify-content: flex-end` (if the `ul` is placed right).